# NDSolve and system of differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I want to solve an optimization problem. I got following code, but it end with no error message or a solution. Note : As of now, I am not using nu1,..nu4 variables even though they are defined in the code. Any insight appreciated.

```
Clear["Derivative"]
ClearAll["Global`*"]
u[c_] := Log[c]; (*Utility Function*)
\[Psi] = 0.36;
f[k_, i_] := ((k)^\[Psi])*((1 - 
       i)^(1 - \[Psi])); (*Physical Production function*)
Subscript[\[Phi], 1] = 2;
Subscript[\[Phi], 2] = 0.1;
Subscript[\[Phi], 3] = 1;
Subscript[\[Phi], 4] = 1;
g[m_] := Subscript[\[Phi], 3]*(m + Subscript[\[Phi], 1])^
   Subscript[\[Phi], 2] - 
  Subscript[\[Phi], 4]*Subscript[\[Phi], 1]^Subscript[\[Phi], 
   2](*health production function*)
funE[A_, e_] := A;   (*Knowledge Production Function*)
Subscript[\[Eta], 1] = 1;
Subscript[\[Beta], 1] = 0.023;
Subscript[\[Beta], 0] = 0.05;
Subscript[\[Eta], 2] = 1;
Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] = 1.01;
Subscript[\[Gamma], 0] = 1;
\[Beta][A_, e_, h_] := 
 Subscript[\[Beta], 1] + 
  Subscript[\[Beta], 0]*
   Exp[-Subscript[\[Eta], 1]*A*e*h]; (*transmission rate*)
\[Gamma][A_, e_, h_] := 
 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] - 
  Subscript[\[Gamma], 0]*
   Exp[-Subscript[\[Eta], 2]*A*e*h]; (*recovery rate*)
Subscript[\[Delta], K] = 0.05; (*Physical Capital Depreciation rate*)
\

Subscript[\[Delta], H] = 0.05; (*Health Capital Depreciation rate*)
Subscript[\[Delta], E] = 0.05 ;(*Knowledge depreciation rate*)
\[Mu] = 0.005; (*Death rate*)
b = 0.037; (*Birth rate*)
p = 0.5 ;(*Vacination rate*)
\[Theta] = 0.006; (*Discount Rate*)

(*Lagrangian*)
L[c_, m_, A_, k_, h_, s_, i_, 
  e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, t_] := u[c] +
  (\[Lambda]1*(f[k, i] - m - A - 
      c - (Subscript[\[Delta], K] + b - \[Mu])*k)) +
  (\[Lambda]2*(g[m] - (Subscript[\[Delta], H] + b - \[Mu])*h)) +
  (\[Lambda]3*((1 - p)*b - b*s - \[Beta][A, e, h]*s*i)) +
  (\[Lambda]4*(\[Beta][A, e, h]*s*i - (\[Gamma][A, e, h] + b)*i)) +
  (\[Lambda]5*(funE[A, e] - Subscript[\[Delta], E]*e));

ceqn[c_, m_, A_, k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, 
   t_] := (D[
     L[c, m, A, k, h, s, i, 
      e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], c] == 0);
meqn[c_, m_, A_, k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, 
   t_] := (D[
     L[c, m, A, k, h, s, i, 
      e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], m] == 0);
Aeqn[c_, m_, A_, k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, 
   t_] := (D[
     L[c, m, A, k, h, s, i, 
      e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], A] == 0);

(*Solve control variable using state, co-state and lagrange \
multiplier variables*)
csol[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, t_] := 
  FullSimplify@(Flatten[
     Solve[ceqn[c, m, A, k, h, s, i, 
       e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], {c}]]);   
msol[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, t_] := 
  FullSimplify@(Flatten[
     Solve[meqn[c, m, A, k, h, s, i, 
       e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], {m}]]);   
Asol[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, t_] := 
  FullSimplify@(Flatten[
     Solve[Aeqn[c, m, A, k, h, s, i, 
       e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], {A}]]);   

(*Substitute those solution back in to the Lagrange equation. Now \
lagrange equation writtien using state and costate variables*)
L2[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, t_] := 
  FullSimplify@
    L[c, m, A, k, h, s, i, 
     e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t] /. 
   Flatten[{csol[k, h, s, i, 
      e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], 
     msol[k, h, s, i, 
      e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], 
     Asol[k, h, s, i, 
      e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t]}];

(*set of equations for state and co-state variables*)
lam1eqn[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, 
   t_] := (D[\[Lambda]1, 
     t ] == -D[
       L2[k, h, s, i, 
        e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \
\[Lambda]5, \[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], 
       k ] + \[Lambda]1*\[Theta]);
lam2eqn[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, 
   t_] := (D[\[Lambda]2, 
     t ] == -D[
       L2[k, h, s, i, 
        e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \
\[Lambda]5, \[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], 
       h] + \[Lambda]2*\[Theta]);
lam3eqn[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, 
   t_] := (D[\[Lambda]3, 
     t ] == -D[
       L2[k, h, s, i, 
        e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \
\[Lambda]5, \[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], 
       s] + \[Lambda]3*\[Theta]);
lam4eqn[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, 
   t_] := (D[\[Lambda]4, 
     t ] == -D[
       L2[k, h, s, i, 
        e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \
\[Lambda]5, \[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], 
       i] + \[Lambda]4*\[Theta]);
lam5eqn[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, 
   t_] := (D[\[Lambda]5, 
     t ] == -D[
       L2[k, h, s, i, 
        e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \
\[Lambda]5, \[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], 
       e] + \[Lambda]5*\[Theta]);

keqn[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, 
   t_] := (D[k, t] == 
    D[L2[k, h, s, i, 
      e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], \[Lambda]1]);
heqn[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, 
   t_] := (D[h, t] == 
    D[L2[k, h, s, i, 
      e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], \[Lambda]2]);
seqn[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, 
   t_] := (D[s, t] == 
    D[L2[k, h, s, i, 
      e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], \[Lambda]3]);
ieqn[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, 
   t_] := (D[i, t] == 
    D[L2[k, h, s, i, 
      e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], \[Lambda]4]);
eeqn[k_, h_, s_, i_, 
   e_, \[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_, \[Lambda]3_, \[Lambda]4_, \
\[Lambda]5_, \[Nu]1_, \[Nu]2_, \[Nu]3_, \[Nu]4_, 
   t_] := (D[e, t] == 
    D[L2[k, h, s, i, 
      e, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2, \[Lambda]3, \[Lambda]4, \[Lambda]5, \
\[Nu]1, \[Nu]2, \[Nu]3, \[Nu]4, t], \[Lambda]5]);

(*Solve for state and co-state variable*)
soln = First@
  NDSolve[{lam1eqn[k[t], h[t], s[t], i[t], 
     e[t], \[Lambda]1[t], \[Lambda]2[t], \[Lambda]3[t], \[Lambda]4[
      t], \[Lambda]5[t], \[Nu]1[t], \[Nu]2[t], \[Nu]3[t], \[Nu]4[t], 
     t],
    lam2eqn[k[t], h[t], s[t], i[t], 
     e[t], \[Lambda]1[t], \[Lambda]2[t], \[Lambda]3[t], \[Lambda]4[
      t], \[Lambda]5[t], \[Nu]1[t], \[Nu]2[t], \[Nu]3[t], \[Nu]4[t], 
     t],
    lam3eqn[k[t], h[t], s[t], i[t], 
     e[t], \[Lambda]1[t], \[Lambda]2[t], \[Lambda]3[t], \[Lambda]4[
      t], \[Lambda]5[t], \[Nu]1[t], \[Nu]2[t], \[Nu]3[t], \[Nu]4[t], 
     t],
    lam4eqn[k[t], h[t], s[t], i[t], 
     e[t], \[Lambda]1[t], \[Lambda]2[t], \[Lambda]3[t], \[Lambda]4[
      t], \[Lambda]5[t], \[Nu]1[t], \[Nu]2[t], \[Nu]3[t], \[Nu]4[t], 
     t],
    lam5eqn[k[t], h[t], s[t], i[t], 
     e[t], \[Lambda]1[t], \[Lambda]2[t], \[Lambda]3[t], \[Lambda]4[
      t], \[Lambda]5[t], \[Nu]1[t], \[Nu]2[t], \[Nu]3[t], \[Nu]4[t], 
     t],
    keqn[k[t], h[t], s[t], i[t], 
     e[t], \[Lambda]1[t], \[Lambda]2[t], \[Lambda]3[t], \[Lambda]4[
      t], \[Lambda]5[t], \[Nu]1[t], \[Nu]2[t], \[Nu]3[t], \[Nu]4[t], 
     t],
    heqn[k[t], h[t], s[t], i[t], 
     e[t], \[Lambda]1[t], \[Lambda]2[t], \[Lambda]3[t], \[Lambda]4[
      t], \[Lambda]5[t], \[Nu]1[t], \[Nu]2[t], \[Nu]3[t], \[Nu]4[t], 
     t],
    seqn[k[t], h[t], s[t], i[t], 
     e[t], \[Lambda]1[t], \[Lambda]2[t], \[Lambda]3[t], \[Lambda]4[
      t], \[Lambda]5[t], \[Nu]1[t], \[Nu]2[t], \[Nu]3[t], \[Nu]4[t], 
     t],
    ieqn[k[t], h[t], s[t], i[t], 
     e[t], \[Lambda]1[t], \[Lambda]2[t], \[Lambda]3[t], \[Lambda]4[
      t], \[Lambda]5[t], \[Nu]1[t], \[Nu]2[t], \[Nu]3[t], \[Nu]4[t], 
     t],
    eeqn[k[t], h[t], s[t], i[t], 
     e[t], \[Lambda]1[t], \[Lambda]2[t], \[Lambda]3[t], \[Lambda]4[
      t], \[Lambda]5[t], \[Nu]1[t], \[Nu]2[t], \[Nu]3[t], \[Nu]4[t], 
     t],
    k[0] == 0.5, h[0] == 0.5, s[0] == 0.8, i[0] == 0.2, 
    e[0] == 0.25, \[Lambda]1[100] == 0, \[Lambda]2[100] == 
     0, \[Lambda]3[100] == 0, \[Lambda]4[100] == 0, \[Lambda]5[100] ==
      0, \[Nu]1[100] == 0, \[Nu]2[100] == 0, \[Nu]3[100] == 
     0, \[Nu]4[100] == 0}, {k, h, s, i, e}, {t, 0, 100}]

Plot[{k[t] /. soln, h[t] /. soln, s[t] /. soln, i[t] /. soln, 
  e[t] /. soln}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"k", "h", "s", "i", "e"}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: I feel may be my differential equations are not really true functions of time t...

Comment: The code is huge, what is your real problem? Can you construct a minimal example?

Comment: Copy/pasting your code into a clean ver 12.3  kernel and running it I get a bunch of error messages (infinite expression, non-numeric values, indeterminate values).  I suggest you break up your code into manageable pieces and run them separately and check the format of the various expressions.  Also the Standard Report style sheet is nice to separate the code and analyze it.  Maybe try this also.